# Expected time to pick up n things when I can drop them each round?

Tags: probability, expectation, information-theory

**Why Can't I Hold All These Limes?**

Suppose I wanted to hold $n$ limes. Each time step, I pick up a lime. But limes are hard to hold, so I also have a probability $p$ to drop a lime on each step which depends on how many limes I am holding. I may drop more than one lime on each time step, but the limes will drop independently.

How long should I expect to be picking up limes before I am holding all $n$?

I'm not exactly sure how to be rigorous here, but I suppose that if $E(t)$ is my expected number of limes at time $t$, then I am asking for a solution to $E(t) = n$ in terms of $p$.

Hints, instead of full solutions, are very welcome.

Comment: "$p$ ... which depends on how many limes I am holding" Is $p$ fixed and each lime has independent probability $p$ of being dropped each round, or if you have $k$ limes then is the probability of dropping a lime $p_k$, i.e. dependent on how many limes you have?

Comment: It is a random walk problem, belongs  to a much studied field. One would need to be precise about the probability model. With fixed $p$ and $0$ or $1$ limes dropped, an answer can be lifted from gambler's ruin.

Comment: I'm thinking of it as $p(x)$ is the probability of dropping a lime where $x$ is the number of limes I have. So the probability of dropping $k$ limes is $p(x)^k$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @AndréNicolas As a walk, would the problem be: Starting at the origin, at each point we walk right one unit, then to the left some number of units depending on $p$?

Comment: Yes, that will do. But except in the simple drop $0$ or $1$ case, I do not know how to solve the resulting recurrence.  For the mean, a conditioning argument that does not require solving for the probabilities will work for the simple case. But again, offhand I do not see how to do it for number dropped having binomial distribution with parameters $p$ and the number we have at the time. My guess is that the problem has been studied, it looks like an interesting model.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can come up with a recurrence for the expected waiting time assuming you have $m$ limes, in terms of the expected waiting time when you have $m' < m$ limes for all $m'$. $E(t) = n$ will not have a finite solution for the expected number of limes held at time $t$ because at any point in time there is always a chance you will have less than $n$ limes. Also that is not quite the right set up to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved numerically as a Markov Chain with an absorbing state (all limes picked). Assuming that at each step one has $0<x_t<n$ limes, and a number of those limes are dropped (according to a Binomial with $p=g(x)$) and a lime is picked (and hence one is always holding at least one lime), an example for $n=6$ and $p = x/24$ (arbitrary), one can construct the transition matrix as

```
n=6   % total number of limes
px = [1:n]/(n*4)  % probabilites of dropping each lime, as a function of the number of holded limes 
P=eye(n); % transition matrix
for n1=1:n-1 ; 
   for n2=1:n1+1;
      d = n1+1-n2; % dropped
      P(n1,n2)= px(n1)^d * (1-px(n1))^(n1-d)*nchoosek(n1,d); % binomial
   endfor
endfor
```

which gives

```
px =
  0.04166   0.08333   0.12500   0.16666   0.20833   0.25000
P=
  0.04167   0.95833   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  0.00694   0.15278   0.84028   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  0.00195   0.04102   0.28711   0.66992   0.00000   0.00000
  0.00077   0.01543   0.11574   0.38580   0.48225   0.00000
  0.00039   0.00746   0.05667   0.21535   0.40916   0.31097
  0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   1.00000
```

And then the [mean time to reach the absorbing state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Expected_number_of_steps) is given by

```
m=n-1;
Q = P(1:m,1:m); % transient submatrix
N=inv(eye(m)-Q);
N*ones(m,1)   % mean time starting from given limes

ans =
   12.2256
   11.1821
    9.9834
    8.4107
    5.8649
```

Hence, starting from 1 lime one has to wait for $12.2$ steps in average ($13.2$ if starting with no limes).